# Avast blocks/deletes wpf .exe file when building in release mode visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I'm developing some WPF application and everything was working just fine, but suddenly I got this annoying error which says:

> `Could not find file 'obj\x86\Release\MIS.exe' avast wpf`

So this happens when I'm building my project in release mode, and what causes it is avast anti virus which treats my .exe as malware. When I disable avast everything builds fine, also when i set this file to avast exclusions list also everything builds fine. This doesn't completely solves my problem because when I try to run this exe on another computer I get the same anti virus problem and my program can't be  run.

What could possibly cause this type of problem and is there any other solutions for this? I just need to make this program to work on many computers because this application is meant to be used by multiple users.

Just to state that I don't get any errors when my debug mode is set to "Debug".

Comment: What is your application doing that an antivirus program is flagging it?

Comment: Isn't this an Avast problem instead of a C#/wpf/visual studio problem... go to an avast forum!

Comment: @MikeStrobel I don't really understand the question. Every time I try to build my project in release mode, it got interrupted and in my output I got the above error. Problem is that my avast antivirus treats my app .exe file as treat and immediately delets it (moves it to chest) so that is why it could not be found while compiling.

Comment: Avast is a very notorious troublemaker on dev machines.  You'll need to get rid of it.  Review the google query hit on "avast and visual studio" for evidence.

Comment: I've been researching about this problem for a 3 days now. Rely can't figure out whats going on. Most strange is that, when building in "Debug" mode everything works just perfect. I thought it must be some code that I recently wrote, but I switched to code that I used like a month ago and I got the same problem. Everything was working fine 4 days ago but now I have this problem out of nowhere...